# Facebook Share doesn't display image

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

What I'm planning is that a user has an option to share his/her uploaded image.
I am retrieving the image name in my MySQL DB.
Here's my simple MySQL SELECT Query :

```
$gallery_select = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_has_photo where user_fbid = :user_fbid");
            $gallery_select->bindParam(':user_fbid', $user_fbid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $gallery_select->execute();
            while ($row = $gallery_select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $img = $row['ImageName'];
            }
```

I've also tried to complete the image's path using the canvas url

Actual PATH :

```
 $image = `"https://localhost/photo/login/uploads/"."{$img}";`
```

Here's the Fb Sharer link:

```
<a onClick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=<?php echo $title;?>&amp;p[summary]=<?php echo $summary;?>&amp;p[url]=<?php echo $url; ?>&amp;p[images][0]=<?php echo $image;?>','sharer',
            'toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');"
            href="javascript: void(0)" class="text-red"><p class="text-center text-button">share here</p></a>
```

I just wonder why it doesn't display the image. When I tried to test the Image's Complete Url in the Browser's Address URL. It displays the desired image.

Or I am totally WRONG with the Idea that facebook can retrieve Values from a different Database and display it on their side.
Thanks.

Comment: `user_fbid = :user_fbid` should be `user_fbid = ':user_fbid'`

Comment: Hi Adam, isn't w/o quotes the right one? But w/o quotes still prints the DB value. So, it's possible to display thumbnails into the facebook share- retrieved from MySQL DB?

Answer (score 0):

you are referring local host image, so that cannot be pulled by facebook. You have to refer a image on public server. that will work.

Comment: Hi Bala, is that an issue, too? What you are trying to say is, it can't retrieve image from localhost although it's properly set in the app details?
Right now, I have it in Live Server, but you see I'm testing it first in my localhost. COuld you please elaborate a little more? Thanks!

Comment: sure, when you send your localhost image path to facebook, facebook will try to pull that URL, and it cannot connect to your localhost, so it will not show image. Even though you specify local path on facebook app setting, which is for completely different purpose.

I know you like to test this on local server. To confirm this, you can specify any image on live server, you will come to know that it is working. cheers

Comment: Nice idea on testing image from Live server. I'll give it a try. Thanks for your time.